# WebGL doesn't work with Chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, chromedriver

I'm having an issue I've hit a wall on, I'm hoping someone else has encountered. I am running selenium/splinter tests on a VM with Chromedriver installed. When I open the webpage on the VM with Chrome the WebGL objects work, when I watch the script run via selenium, the WebGL objects error.

So far I have checked the Chrome settings in `chrome://flags/` and everything is enabled. I've updated my chromedriver. What are some other potential things I might check out? I haven't been able to reproduce this issue on my local machine.

The error I'm getting is:

> WebGL not enabled

where the WebGL object would normally be displayed. Which WebGL is enabled when opened via the browser.

Comment: what is this error you got?

Comment: @YuZhang Added and edit. It just seems via Chromedriver WebGL is not enabled. But only running via chromedriver.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040370/how-do-i-enable-webgl-in-headless-chrome-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify webgl is activated. Type on chrome address bar:
`chrome://gpu/`
You should see:

[image]

If not, follow this steps:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar
3. Press Ctrl + f and type ” Rendering list “, “Override software rendering list” should come up, Now click on Enable and restart the browser
4. Completely kill Chrome: Type `killall chrome` into a console.
5. Go to `chrome://settings` and enable Use hardware acceleration when available. By default it is off since version 43

Answer (score 1):

You might have to run Chrome using a profile (set the capabilities when defining your WebDriver). I had to do that to get the DRM component to work.

*Note:* This will not work if any Chrome process is currently running. Be sure to close all Chrome processes before running your test(s) and only run 1 test at a time on any one machine (no parallel runs on one machine).

**C# Code:**

```
// Create an options object to specify command line arguments for the Chrome web driver
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Use a real profile so that all components load
string localAppData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData");
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=" + localAppData + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\");
options.AddArgument(@"--profile-directory=Default");
// Allow components to update (some components will not load if out of date)
options.AddExcludedArgument(@"disable-component-update");
// Disable extensions (optional, not needed to set/use a profile)
options.AddArgument(@"--disable-extensions");
```